# Making user-input console StopWatch for Java

Tags: java, user-input, stopwatch

I have the code to create a stopwatch in Java already and it works, but I need to make the output appear on the console instead of another window and I'm not sure how to go about that.

Also, the time starts counting immediately, and I'm not sure how to make it so that it only starts when the user inputs "start" and ends the counting when they input "end".

I'm really stuck on this part.

Any help and tips is appreciated, thank you!

My code:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class StopWatch extends JFrame implements ActionListener, Runnable
{
 private long startTime;
 private final static java.text.SimpleDateFormat timerFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("mm : ss.SSS");
 private final JButton startStopButton= new JButton("Start/stop");
 private Thread updater;
 private boolean isRunning= false;
 private final Runnable displayUpdater= new Runnable()
     {
     public void run()
         {
         displayElapsedTime(System.currentTimeMillis() - StopWatch.this.startTime);
     }
 };
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
     {
     if(isRunning)
         {
         long elapsed= System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
         isRunning= false;
         try
             {
             updater.join();
             // Wait for updater to finish
         }
         catch(InterruptedException ie) {}
         displayElapsedTime(elapsed);
         // Display the end-result
     }
     else
         {
         startTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
         isRunning= true;
         updater= new Thread(this);
         updater.start();
     }
 }
 private void displayElapsedTime(long elapsedTime)
     {
     startStopButton.setText(timerFormat.format(new java.util.Date(elapsedTime)));
 }
 public void run()
     {
     try
         {
         while(isRunning)
             {
             SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(displayUpdater);
             Thread.sleep(50);
         }
     }
     catch(java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException ite)
         {
         ite.printStackTrace(System.err);
         // Should never happen!
     }
     catch(InterruptedException ie) {}
     // Ignore and return!
 }
 public StopWatch()
     {
     startStopButton.addActionListener(this);
     getContentPane().add(startStopButton);
     setSize(100,50);
     setVisible(true);
 }
 public static void main(String[] arg)
     {
     new StopWatch().addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
         {
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
             {
             System.exit(0);
         }
     });
 }
```

}

Comment: `System.out.println` will make it output in the console, but do you mean you need to make a "complete" console version?

Comment: Yes, I meant a complete console version, is it possible to do that by just modifying the code I have now or will I have to create a console-specific code?

Comment: Well, with a little work you could create a single stop watch class which could run on both